# NamespaceManager.CreateSubscription throws MessagingEntityNotFoundException

Tags: azure, servicebus

I've also set up other subscriptions and they work.
But when I'm trying to empty the queue of a subscription, the subscription no longer exists.
What I'm trying to do is make a new subscription

`if (!namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(TopicName, SubscriptionName))
            {
                SubscriptionDescription subscription = new SubscriptionDescription(TopicName, SubscriptionName)
                {
                    DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                    LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20),
                    EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = true,
                    EnableDeadLetteringOnFilterEvaluationExceptions = true
                };
                namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(subscription);
            }`

The last line (`CreateSubscription`) throws a MessagingEntityNotFoundException.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Had to make a topic first.

```
if (!namespaceManager.TopicExists(TopicName))
{
    var td = new TopicDescription(TopicName);
    td.MaxSizeInMegabytes = 5120;
    namespaceManager.CreateTopicAsync(td);
}
```